# How to check if my DB user like 'DataMigratorUser' has db_owner permission on 'DataMigrator' table

Tags: sql

How to check if my DB user like 'DataMigratorUser' has db_owner permission on 'DataMigrator' table
I need to write c# code to check if my configured user has db_owner permission on some particular database via SQL query

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh , Its SQL

Comment: SQL is a language supported by a number of products. db_owner permission is a product specific thing, not covered by the ISO/ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: @jarlh,I am not sure what you are asking. I just need sql query for the same

Comment: @jarlh , i have the below query for find the db_owner permission but it don't specify which database....SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT user_name(member_principal_id) as memberName FROM sys.database_role_members WHERE user_name(role_principal_id) ='db_owner'AND user_name(member_principal_id) = 'sa')THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'check'

Comment: Since @HarjeetSingh wrote `db_owner` probably uses MSSQL. @HarjeetSingh better to put what did you try, what results did you get, so others will have better understanding of your context.

Comment: @endo64 This is the link what i have tried till now. This does work for all the user except "sa" . Just replace your database name and db user ..https://sqlgeekspro.com/query-to-retrieve-all-permissions-for-a-user-in-selective-databases/#comment-52254